# From the optaplanner examples: which rule makes sure every team gets assigned at least once?

Tags: optaplanner

In the optaplanner tennis solution, there's a rule that makes sure every team gets assigned an equal amount of times (if I understand correctly at least). That's the fairAssignmentCountPerTeam rule.

What I don't see is how a team doesn't get totally excluded from being assigned.

My actual problem: I want to do a similar thing, though different ;)
In my case, I want to assign players to a field (4 since it's about organising doubles in padel or tennis).
But suppose I have 4 field, so 16 players needed and I have 25 players.
There will be multiple confrontations (different timeslots) for playing.
So how can I make sure that all players will be taken into account?
And that it's not a continuous game play among e.g. a set of 16 players.

I would like to create a similar rule as fairAssignmentCountPerTeam (maybe four of those rules, one for each player on the field). But I don't see a constraint saying that all teams (players) should get assigned over all time slots.

Don't know if my question is clear enough.
Let me know what extra information could help. (I am new to optaplanner)

Answer (score 0):

In the tennis example, every assignment (day + indexInDay) must be assigned to a team, because the tennis example does not use overconstrained planning (it does have `nullable = true` in `@PlannigVariable(...)`). So it can not leave the `TeamAssignment.team = null`.

Now, let's look at that constraint:

```
   Constraint fairAssignmentCountPerTeam(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(TeamAssignment.class)
                .groupBy(loadBalance(TeamAssignment::getTeam))
                .penalize("fairAssignmentCountPerTeam", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM,
                        result -> (int) result.getZeroDeviationSquaredSumRootMillis());
    }
```

Given 40 assignments and 10 teams, it can:

- A) Assign all 40 assignments to team 1, resulting in a penalty of `40 * 40 = 1600`
- B) Assign 20 assignments to team 1 and 20 to team 2, resulting in a penalty of `20 * 20 + 20 * 20 = 800`
- C) Assign 4 assignments to each of the 10 teams, resulting in a penalty of `10 * (4 * 4) = 160`

Obviously C) is the lowest penalty. By not assigning assignments to one team, the penalty of another team exponentially increases, so it won't do that.